# POST request content not visible on my site

Tags: python, php, http, http-post, web-hosting

So basically I have a website on *000webhost* and I have a python program. That python program sends a data to my site using the *requests* module. The problem is that I don't see the sent data on my php based website.

The problem is not with the python program I think because it didn't return any error messages and in *Fiddler* I see the http request coming to the site. Even if I print out the contents of the live page in python, it prints out the right form with the data visible. But somehow still, on the webpage I can't see the data. I tried refreshing the page and I also tried echo *var_dump($_POST)* but it's returning an empty array.

Here are my codes:

**sender.py**:

```
import requests

input("PRESS ENTER TO START")
print("")

url = "http://mysite.cf/page.php" #I'm using .cf free domain

data = {"data": "This is a test message"}

response = requests.post(url, data=data)

try:
    if response.status_code == 200:
        page = response.text
        print(page)
    else:
        print("Request failed with status code:",response.status_code)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)

print("")
input("")
```

And here is the server side code:

**page.php**:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    echo "The message received from HTTP request: $data";
}
else{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: the site does not work, what were you expecting ?

Comment: It's working, I just didn't want to give away my real site address.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a Way. Basically I save the post variable to a database and then from there I Select Data etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).